# Problems with arduino tone command

Tags: audio, if-statement, arduino

I am trying to make an *Arduino Piano* with analog sensors as keys.  However, all of the keys produce the same tone, the tone produced doesn't appear anywhere in the program. When multiple keys are pressed simultaneously, the tone alternates between the two expected tones and the undefined tone is not produced.  I checked which if else commands are being activated when keys are touched, and they all activate only when their corresponding keys are pressed.

```
#define Note_C 65.41   //Hz   
#define Note_D 73.42   //Hz   
#define Note_E 82.41   //Hz
#define Note_F 87.31   //Hz
#define Note_G 98      //Hz
#define Note_A 110     //Hz  
#define threshold 1000  


const int speaker=3;  
const int B_1=A0;    // pins A0-A5 have sensors attatched to them 
const int B_2=A1;    // pins 13-8 are being used to power each sensor
const int B_3=A2;     
const int B_4=A3;     
const int B_5=A4;
const int B_6=A5;
const int P_1=13;
const int P_2=12;
const int P_3=11;
const int P_4=10;
const int P_5=9;
const int P_6=8;


int val_1=0;
int val_2=0;
int val_3=0;
int val_4=0;
int val_5=0;
int val_6=0; 


void setup()
{   
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(P_1, OUTPUT);      
digitalWrite(P_1, HIGH);
pinMode(P_2, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(P_2, HIGH);
pinMode(P_3, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(P_3, HIGH);
pinMode(P_4, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(P_4, HIGH);
pinMode(P_5, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(P_5, HIGH);
pinMode(P_6, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(P_6, HIGH);
}


void loop()
{
  analogRead(B_1); // checks each sensor value and stores it
  delay(1);              // each value must be checked twice with a 
  val_1=analogRead(B_1); // delay inbetween to provide consistant values
  analogRead(B_2);
  delay(1);
  val_2=analogRead(B_2);
  analogRead(B_3);
  delay(1);
  val_3=analogRead(B_3);
  analogRead(B_4);
  delay(1);
  val_4=analogRead(B_4);
  analogRead(B_5);
  delay(1);
  val_5=analogRead(B_5);
  analogRead(B_6);
  delay(1);
 val_6=analogRead(B_6);

 if (val_1 < threshold)     
  {
  tone (speaker, Note_C);
  Serial.println("1");
}
    else
   {
     noTone (speaker);   
   }     
 if (val_2 < threshold)     
  {
    Serial.println("2");
  tone (speaker, Note_D);
} 
    else
{ 
  noTone(speaker);
}
 if (val_3 < threshold)     
  {
    Serial.println("3");
  tone (speaker, Note_E);
} 
    else
   { 
     noTone (speaker);
   }
 if (val_4 < threshold) 
  {
  Serial.println("4");
  tone (speaker, Note_F);
}
    else 
    {
      noTone (speaker);
    }
  if (val_5 < threshold)
  {
  Serial.println("5");
  tone (speaker, Note_G);
}
    else
   {
     noTone (speaker);
   }
  if (val_6 < threshold) 
   {
   Serial.println("6");
   tone (speaker, Note_A);
   }
    else
   {
     noTone (speaker);
   }
    noTone(speaker);
  }
```

I know *arrays* would be more efficient, but I want to get this working first.  I am also a beginning programmer, so any other advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're activating and deactivating the tone constantly, every time round the loop. I think a better approach would be to start the tone when a particular input is activated, and keep playing it until the input is deactivated. (You can't play multiple notes at the same time using `tone()`.)

You would need to store the number of the currently playing tone in a variable. Something like this might work:

```
int currentTone = 0;

void loop()
{
    // (take your analog readings here)


    if (val_1 < threshold)
    {
        if (currentTone == 0)
        {
            tone(speaker, Note_C);
            currentTone = 1;
        }
    }
    else if (currentTone == 1)
    {
        noTone(speaker);
        currentTone = 0;
    }

    if (val_2 < threshold)
    {
        if (currentTone == 0)
        {
            tone(speaker, Note_D);
            currentTone = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (currentTone == 2)
    {
        noTone(speaker);
        currentTone = 0;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

This goes through each input to check if it has been activated. If so, and if no other tone is currently playing, it starts playing the corresponding note. If an input is not active, but its corresponding note is playing, it stops it.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much.  This has been bugging me for quite some time